# Vesta graphs and Digitalocean graphs on RAM usage are not the same

Tags: server, digital-ocean, vesta

The server of my website is on Digitalocean

Vesta graphs shows all of the RAM capacity is used in a situation that Digitalocean graphs shows only 33% of RAM is uses. Which one is correct? 
Why there is this difference ?

Answer (score 0):

Vesta likes to display **cached RAM** as **used up RAM**. Where DigitalOcean usually shows **cached RAM** as **free RAM.**

I think you should go with DigitalOcean's statistics as cached RAM is generally counted as free RAM.